# Can someone help me install this program onto Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, arm

I recently converted to ubuntu, and I'm still figuring out how to work around things. I'm a student in school and I am required to use a certain software called ARMsim# 
from here http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/Documentation.html

I found this documentation on their website that was titled for Linux and Mac but I can't find the Linux instructions anywhere. Are the instructions the same for Linux? http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/AttachedFiles/ArmSimOnMacInstruction.pdf

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the instructions? since they say, download and install mono. And mono has some Linux support. And yes, the commands listed there should work on Linux too.

Comment: I apologize for such a late reply, I did install, and it seems to be working. Thank you again for your time, and I do apologize for getting back so late. Thank you

Comment: @user2230712 I realize this is kind of old, but how did you get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your software is for Windows only, you need a *Compatibility Layer*.

On their website, they say they tested it with Mono on Mac OS X. You may be also able to use it on Linux.

The easiest way to do this is to install PlayOnLinux (via the USC or `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`). PlayOnLinux is a GUI Frontend for the compatibility layer Wine (http://www.winehq.org). Wine itself will download and setup Mono, if needed, as in your case, but Wine provides additional libraries that may be needed to use certain programs.

1. Install PlayOnLinux and open it.
2. Install the latest Wine version (Tools -> Manage Wine versions)
3. Afterwards click *Install* in the main window.
4. Hit the *install software that is not listed* in the bottom left corner of the new window.
5. Keep the default settings in the wizard and give the path to the Windows Installer (Setup.exe, Setup.msi, whatever)
6. Wait for the program to install, then create a shortcut of the executable
7. Finish and run the program.

I hope it works. If not, ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

The OS X version requires some significant tweaking that the Linux version doesn't. That's why there's a separate document. You can see this on the [Downloads page](http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/DownloadARMSimSharp.html).

This software runs in Mono, which is an open source implementation of the Microsoft .NET framework.

1. So first you need to make sure it's installed. You can install it with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mono-complete
   ```

   Depending on your version, you may already have it.
2. Next, you'll need to get ARMSim#.

   It appears that there's only [one link](http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/Downloads/ARMSim-191-MAC.zip) available for the Linux or Mac version. Judging by the name (it has "MAC" in it), I'm thinking there must be another one but their "Downloads" directory is not browseable.
3. Next, unzip it:

   ```
   unzip ARMSim*.zip
   ```
4. Then go to the created folder:

   ```
   cd ARMSim-1.91
   ```
5. Finally, run it:

   ```
   mono ARMSim.exe
   ```

Comment: Tried this method too, but I got an error:                                  **Could not set X locale modifiers**

Comment: On the last step?

Comment: When I tried loading mono ArmSim.exe in terminal

Comment: `strace` please, but from what I can tell, this would require a patch from the developer. Check in with them.